# Changing group from user to root

Tags: macos, unix

I am using mac and I am trying to change my `open file limit` by modifying the following directory:

`/Library/LaunchDaemons`

when I created two files I got the following permissions:

```
-rw-r--r--@ 1 root        wheel  535 Jul  2 16:36 limit.maxfiles.plist
-rw-r--r--@ 1 samu        wheel  586 Jul  2 16:53 limit.maxproc.plist
```

however when I run `limit.maxproc.plist` file I get the following error:

`/Library/LaunchDaemons/limit.maxproc.plist: Path had bad ownership/permissions`

which is due to the permissions of my group.

I want to change the group from `samu` to `root` but not sure how?

Comment: not really a programming code Q. More appropriate to https://apple.stackexchange.com . Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. To change a specific file owner to root you can use the following command :

`sudo chown root limit.maxproc.plist`